# How to create iPhone app without user operation in response to the iBeacon detection

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible the following behaviors on my iPhone app ?

1) Proccess begins in background ,when detecting iBeacon wave.

2) Proccess begins with a screen, when detecting iBeacon wave, but
   the application will finish automatically(without any user operations) after proseccing.

Answer (score 0):

To simply put it, no. In order for your code to execute in the first place, the user needs to tap on the app. That sort of style application MAY be able to work on Android, but not on iPhone.

You CANNOT start an application from the background.

Also, when it's in the background, you CANNOT bring its UI up and obstruct what the user's trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your polite answer. I entirely give up this.

Comment: I'm sorry that the app didn't get to go how you wanted it to. Continue to look for inspiration, and continue to think of ideas that might someday be a revolution!